# How to copy a folder and keep the structure?

Tags: function, delphi, copy-paste

I am creating a function that copies a folder and pastes it with another name.

Therefore, I have my "Main" folder and according to the query I make copies of the folder called like this: "Main 1", "Main 2", "Main 3"

The way I managed to solve this was through this function:

```
function TDMMonitor.CopyFolder(Origin, Destination : String) : Boolean;
var
  aFiles : TStringDynArray;
  InFile, OutFile: string;
Begin
  aFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles(Origin, '*.*',  TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);

  for InFile in aFiles do
    Begin
      OutFile := TPath.Combine(Destination , TPath.GetFileName(InFile));
      TFile.Copy(InFile, OutFile, True);
    End;
  Result := True;
End;
```

This works! But my problem right now is that the parent folder has subfolders that are not being copied correctly.

I leave a more visual example of the results of my function below:

"**Main**" folder:

- File.txt
- File1.txt
- *Sub-Folder* -> File3.txt

"**Main 1**" folder:

- File.txt
- File1.txt
- File3.txt

**How can I maintain the folder structure that the Main folder follows?**

Comment: You can use `IFileOperation`.

Comment: Yes as @AndreasRejbrand says, why reinvent the wheel when the system already has the functionality you need.

Answer (score 3):

[TDirectory.Copy](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.Copy) works:

```
TDirectory.Copy('D:\Path\Main', 'D:\Path\Main 1');
```

Answer (score 1):

`TDirectory.GetFiles()` returns an array of *absolute* paths to each file found. The `soAllDirectories` flag tells it to search through subfolders *recursively*. So, you will end up with an array of paths at potentially different levels.

`TPath.GetFileName()` strips off all folder path info, leaving just the file name.

Based on your example, you are searching recursively through `C:\Main\` and you want to copy everything to `C:\Main 1\`. When the search gives you the file `C:\Main\Sub-Folder\File3.txt`, your use of `TPath.GetFileName()` discards `C:\Main\Sub-Folder\`, and so you concatenate `C:\Main 1\` with just `File3.txt`, thus you copy `C:\Main\Sub-Folder\File3.txt` to `C:\Main 1\File3.txt` instead of to `C:\Main 1\Sub-Folder\File3.txt`.

That is why your subfolders are not copying correctly.

Rather than using `TPath.GetFileName()`, you would need to replace *only* the `Origin` portion of each returned absolute path (`C:\Main\`) with the `Destination` path (`C:\Main 1\`), leaving everything else in the path intact. Thus, `C:\Main\Sub-Folder\File3.txt` would become `C:\Main 1\Sub-Folder\File3.txt`.

Otherwise, don't use `soAllDirectories` at all.  Recurse through the subfolders manually using `TDirectory.GetDirectories()` instead, so that you are handling only 1 level of folders at a time.